# Disable number_field when radio button is not checked

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a form and only show a number_field if it's relative radio button is checked. I'm able to hide the number_field with CSS, but since all the number_fields have the same name, the app only saves at the database the last field (even if its related radio is unchecked, since the CSS is only hiding the field). There is a way to send the number_field data to database only if it's relative radio button is checked?

To illustrate the problem with other words: If this code generates 5 radio buttons, when it is sent to the database, the value of the last number_field is the final value written in the database, while I wish that only the value of the number_field with the relative radio_button selected is sent to the database.

There is a way of doing that within the controller or the model?

My view:

```
<% @shipping_method_list.each do |shipping| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.radio_button :shipping_method_id, shipping.id %>
    <% @sm_id = :shipping_method_id.to_s + "_" + shipping.id.to_s %>
    <%= f.label @sm_id, shipping.name %>
    <span class="reveal-if-active">Cost: <%= f.number_field :shipping_cost %></span> # This is what I want to disable when the radio isn't checked.
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And my CSS:

```
.reveal-if-active {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Does your `ShippingMethod` object in your `.each` loop have some value that determines whether or not it ought to have a numerical value associated with it?

Comment: Sorry but i'm not sure if I understood your question since I'm new to RoR and not that good with english. On the controller I used this: `@shipping_method_list = ShippingMethod.all.order(:name)`. Also, the shipping_method has_many orders (and this one belongs_to), so on the database it saves the ID of the shipping method on the orders table. So I guess it has a numerical value associated. This answers the question?

Comment: Basically, I'm asking if there is a simple `if` statement that filters out the shipping methods that don't require a number input. Perhaps adding a column to the `ShippingMethod` model like `requires_number:boolean` and toggle it to true if you need a number input. But if something already exists, then you don't need to add an extra column to your tables.

Comment: You should move `shipping_cost` outside the loop and have only one input field for cost.Then radio button will save the selected `shipping_method_id ` and input field will save  `shipping_cost` to the database.

Comment: Yes that works and it was on my original layout, but I wanted that the number_field shows inline with the radio that is checked for styling reasons, so I need one number_field to each line. Although my intention was to do this only with RoR, I managed to get this working disabling the elements with javascript, since I do not have that time to learn how to do it now (have to finish this project soon). Thanks for helping @Okomikeruko and PGill

Answer (score 0):

Well, although I was trying to use only RoR for that, I was without time to learn how to do, so I just used javascript to disable the elements that is not in use (disable the number_field when radio_button is unchecked). This way the database will only be written with the number_field enabled.

Thanks all for helping.